# Can't modify date field in the recursive view

Tags: sql, oracle, recursive-query

I'm trying to use recursive view to generate some data but it works different from how I expected. Each time one day is deducted from start date:

```
with x (id, start_date, tmp) as
    (
    select id, start_date, 1 from my_table
    union all
    select id+1, start_date + tmp, tmp+1 from x where id <=5
    )
    select * from x
```

Result:

```
2015-03-01 00:00:00.0 
2015-02-28 00:00:00.0  
2015-02-27 00:00:00.0
2015-02-26 00:00:00.0 
2015-02-25 00:00:00.0
```

Then I tried to test it with a simpler example and got error:

```
with x (id, date_test) as
(
    select 1, trunc(to_date('01/01/2015','dd/mm/yyyy')) from dual
    union all
    select id+1, date_test from x where id <=5
)
select * from x
```

Error:

> Error: ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding
>   expression SQLState:  42000 ErrorCode: 1790 Position: 114

Query

```
select 1, trunc(to_date('01/03/2015','dd/mm/yyyy')) 
from dual
```

is valid:

```
  1   2015-01-01 00:00:00.0
```

Actually i worked around using connect by but i wonder why this happens. I used to work with Sql Server and there this approach works, but in oracle i still can't find the reason why does it happen.

Comment: Unrelated, but: the `trunc()` is useless. The result of your `to_date()` call will have the time part set to `00:00:00` anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, it's due to a bug in 11.2. Fixed in 12.1, according to MOS Bug 11840579.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, are you perhaps simply being confused because the rows are not coming out in the order you expect?  With no explicit `ORDER BY` on the query, you should not assume that the first row returned is what you think of as the "first" row.

Your second example works as written for me (in Oracle 11g), with no error.

Comment: the 2nd query fails for me in 11.2.0.2

Comment: In the first example start date also was '01/03/2015', so i expected to get next 02/03, 03/03 and so on, but i got 28/02 instead.